# Replace quote characters with better ones

Tags: javascript, html

I have a webpage where I want to replace all standard quote characters `"` with the nicer looking quotes. For example, we have

`"hello world"`

which would be replaced with

`&ldquo;hello world&rdquo;`

in markup, showing the much better looking 'curly' quotes.

The two HTML special characters are pairs, in that they "open" and "close" a quote block, instead of being a generic double dash, which is where I'm struggling - simply replacing all quotes with `&ldquo;` is easy, but I want to do it so the open/close pairs are respected.

Comment: Is there a space before and after the qoutes? then with almost every ordinary texteditor you can find and replace space" with space&ldquo; and "space with &rdquo;space.

Comment: @Tim: It appears I'm far less intelligent than I first thought - thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be missing something obvious here, but I think the following RegEx solution would work -

```
subject = 'test "abc" test "abc"';
result = subject.replace(/"([A-Za-z ]*)"/ig, "&ldquo;$1&rdquo;");
alert(result);
```

If you were using PHP then you could write some similar code in PHP - (my PHP skills are somewhat lacking though! The code below was generated with RegEx Buddy so it hasn't been tested and may need changing)

```
$subject = 'test "abc" test "abc"';    
$result = preg_replace('/"([A-Za-z ]*)"/i', '&ldquo;$1&rdquo;', $subject);
```

Alternatively, you could load the content into a DIV using PHP then use JavaScript to change the DIV contents, here's a bit of JQuery that would do the job -

```
$("#contentdiv").text($("#contentdiv").text().replace(/"([A-Za-z ]*)"/ig, "&ldquo;$1&rdquo;"));
```

There's a jsfiddle that demonstrates the above JQuery [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qsgBZ/).

Comment: Thanks ipr. Would this be adaptable for putting back into the HTML document, so that I can show these new quotes in the page?

Comment: How is your page getting served? Is it a static HTML page or is being rendered by php etc?

Comment: PHP unfortunately. If there's a way to alter the PHP output stream, I'd happily go with that providing there isn't a major performance hit.

Answer (score 3):

In case you have a string like `test "abc" test "abc"`, you can check for each `"` whether it should be an opening or closing one by looking at how many `"` are preceeding it:

If it's an even amount it should be `&ldquo;`, otherwise `&rdquo;`.

```
var str = 'test "abc" test "abc"';
var splitted = str.split('"');
var result = '';
for(var i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++) {
    result += splitted[i] + ( i % 2 == 0 ? '&ldqou;' : '&rdquo;' );
}
result = result.substring(0, result.length - 7); // remove last appended &ldquo;
```

Comment: Thanks very much pimvdp. The issue here is that I want to replace all instances of a quote in an entire HTML document, so the quotes inside tags would be replaced, leaving a broken page.

Comment: @JamWaffles: That's tricky because there's no easy way of determining whether it is part of the HTML markup or not. You'd need a HTML parser of some kind, but it will be more complicated.