# How do I replace all left apostrophes with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, replace, str-replace

Sorry I have a problem with with the fancy left apostrophe showing up in Chrome as well as other special characters. I tried to globally replace the “ with `&ldquo;` but it won't and it took the question mark errors out of the document but it also replaced the right apostrophe with the left apostrophe as well. Then it broke my javascript text cufon script from working too. Here is my code.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",replaceall);
function replaceall(){
    var content = document.getElementById("content");
    content.innerHTML = content.innerHTML.replace(/“/g,"&ldquo;");

}
```

Here is a link to the page I'm working on: http://reachhighernow.com/?page=attunement

Comment: This might be an encoding issue. What encoding is the document coded in?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html> Here is the doctype. Is this what you want to know?

Comment: No, the encoding of the document is how the characters are parsed by the browser, as in is it utf8, ISO-whatever, what?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708815/replace-quote-characters-with-better-ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to fix the problem right instead of using a work-around java-script.
Most of the times the declaration of charset is not right.
For example in html you have to put this in your head-tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

**IF** your pages (html-files, php-files) are saved as utf-8 documents. (this could be also ISO-XXXX, if so, just change the value of the declaration).

You can look this up in the properties of an document or even change the encoding of the document in your editor (e.g. eclipse, notepad++).

Comment: I added this meta tag but it didn't fix it. Here is the link to the page I'm working on: http://reachhighernow.com/?page=attunement. It shows up correct in firefox.

Comment: The page is currently encoded as `windows-1252`. So just change the `UTF-8` to `windows-1252` and you're good.

Comment: yeah, encoding problem. ISO-8859-1 should be the right for you.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Lister the windows-1252 fixed it.

Comment: @JohannesStaehlin While most browsers use ISO-8859-1 as an alias for windows-1252, I'd recommend using windows-125 if you mean windows-1252!

Comment: thanks, I just changed the encoding in the browser and saw it was working. New for me, the alias stuff, but good to know.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the unicode value in your regex instead:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",replaceall);
function replaceall(){
    var content = document.getElementById("content");
    content.innerHTML = content.innerHTML.replace(/\u201c/g,"&ldquo;");
}
```

Right quote would be `/\u201d/`