# How to automatically replace \n with <br > in the current document text (as opposed to any string)

Tags: jquery, html, web

I'm looking for a piece of code like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6709301/2924421) (the jquery one at the end) except instead of replacing the current html document's quotes, it replaces the current html document's \n's or \r\n with the line break tag instead.

The trivial solution of

```
$("#contentdiv").text($("#contentdiv").text().replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, "<br />"));
```

Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Try using the .html function in JQuery instead of .text.  It's similar, but supports HTML instead of stripping it out

Comment: Do you mean `$("#contentdiv").html($("#contentdiv").html().replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, "<br />"));`? Because that still didn't seem to work.

Comment: @Prospector, the difference is that that answer is replacing it in a string, I'm trying to replace it in the current document. Specifically using `$("#contentdiv").html($("#contentdiv").html().replace("\n", "<br />", "g"));` which is the answer given there does not work.

Comment: So you're trying to replace it for the entire body?  Could you do `$("body").html($("body").html(` ... ?

Comment: Yes, sorry I did mean body, though as I mentioned below that wasn't my issue (it was how I was trying to call the script cause I'm a noob at web programming). Your comment is probably a more accurate answer to what I meant to be asking, however the given answer also works since an example is provided that has the div.

Comment: Could you just use CSS, white-space:pre ?

Comment: Yes, however I also wanted to not add whitespace before and after $$ $$ expressions and not add it at the start and end, so this was (the beginning of) a more flexible solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JQuery [text](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function strips out HTML.  Instead use the [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function in JQuery:

I've posted an example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/sm06f35j/

That is using the exact code from your comment:

```
$("#contentdiv").html($("#contentdiv").html().replace(/(?:\n\r|\r\n|\r|\n)/g, "<br />"));
```

Comment: Thanks, it was actually just an issue with how I inlined my javascript. As a sidenote that regular expression actually has an error in that it removes the last character, /(?:\n\r|\r\n|\r|\n)/g  is a better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

For those that are interested, here is the code I ended up using. The above solution also had the problem of adding an extra enter at the start, and I wanted to trim enters from the start and end anyway, so the following does that.

Note this also affects the body instead of a div, though like the above it can be easily modified to affect any piece of the html since jquery is awesome.

```
$(function () {
    var bodyHtml = $("body").html().replace("\r", "");
    var bodyHtmlLines = bodyHtml.split("\n");

    // Mark where to want to stop (to remove all newlines at the end)
    var indexFollowedByOnlyBlanks = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < bodyHtmlLines.length; i++) {
        if (bodyHtmlLines[i].trim().length != 0) {
            indexFollowedByOnlyBlanks = i;
        }
    }


    var resultHtml = "";
    var ignoreFirstEnters = true; // This is for removing all the newlines at the start
    for (i = 0; i < bodyHtmlLines.length; i++) {
        if (bodyHtmlLines[i].trim().length != 0 || !ignoreFirstEnters) {
            resultHtml += bodyHtmlLines[i] + "<br />";

            ignoreFirstEnters = false;
        }

        if (i == indexFollowedByOnlyBlanks) break;
    }

    $("body").html(resultHtml);

    alert(resultHtml);
});
```

And there's a jsfiddle demoing this here:

http://jsfiddle.net/pdswytu0/3/